# bash / regex for reconstructing a partially inconsistent file using complex patterns

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I need reconstruct a file by splitting each line into 4 segments and inserting a delimiter like a pipe or : inbetween each segment. My problem is that the structure is somewhat inconsistent...

the file looks like this:

```
MIKE TESTUSER Some Text 21 - Etc BLA 43 BLA  - Some, Additional..12 info

STEVE NOBODY 43 More `Text and So on BLA (MORE ADDITIONAL info)

LEROY ANYONE Again some text chars numbers BLABLA
```

and i need to split it into name : address : city and optional zip : optional additional info

```
MIKE TESTUSER|Some Text 21 - Etc|BLA43 BLA|- Some, Additional..12 info

STEVE NOBODY|43 More `Text and So on|BLA|(MORE ADDITIONAL info)

LEROY ANYONE|Again some text chars, numbers|BLABLA
```

first segment is always in uppercase, no numbers or special chars
second segment consists of anything except words in uppercase
third segment is only uppercase and sometimes numbers
last segment can be anything except words in uppercase

would be great if someone has a solution for this or can point me into a direction that gets me close (doesn't have to be perfect)

---

first of all thanks for the quick replies! i've tried to explode each line into array elements using the blanks and then check each element for upper/lowercase, numbers etc. somewhat like charlies awk approach. the problem is that i can't always determine when my delimiter has to be placed since a segment sometimes ends with a number or non-alphanumerical char and the next segment starts with a number/non-alphanumerical char.

for example

THIS NAME 23 Rue da guerre 321 12345 MARSEILLE - Info

should look like

THIS NAME|23 Rue da guerre 321|12345 MARSEILLE|- Info

the file has a couple thousand lines and is really messy. quite often the zip code
comes in front of the city and sometimes behind it plus various other inconsistencies..

i know i'll have to reedit it manually in any case but i was hoping to find a solution that
makes it not all that time consuming :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We shouldn't be writing this from scratch for you :-)

Comment: Your rules have an ambiguity: in your last example the second delimiter could come before the `321` or after the `12345`.

Answer (score 2):

Must it be just bash?  I'd seriously think about writing something like a simple Awk program.

Say, as a start

```
awk -f 'BEGIN {FS=" "; uplow=0;}
              {uplow=1;
               for(i=1; i < $NF; i++){
                  if(uplow && ($i ~ [A-Z])) out += $i+" "
                  else if (uplow && ($i !~ [A-Z])) {
                       uplow = 0;
                       out += "|"
                  } else if # fill in the other cases
                }
                print out
               }'
```

The idea is to check each blank-delimited field for case, and keep a flag to remember if you're in a run of upper-case items or lower case items.  What you change, add your pipe character to the output.

Answer (score 1):

You really need a full blown language like Perl. It'd be something like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open MY_FILE "myFileName" or die qq(Can't open "myFileName" for reading\n);
while (my $line = <MY_FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ /([A-Z\s]+)(.*)([A-Z\d\s]{2,})(.*);
    print join "|", ($1, $2, $3, $4) . "\n";
}
```

The big trick is the regular expression in:

```
$line =~ /([A-Z\s]+)(.*)([A-Z\d\s])(.*);
```

That's what breaks the line into four parts (which are then represented by `$1` through `$4`). I don't simply have enough data to even start to test it.

Can you attach about 4 to 5 lines of file to your question, and I'll work something out?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^\([A-Z ]*\) \(.*\)/\2\n\1|/;s/[A-Z]\{2\}/|&/;s/\([^|]*|\)\(.*\)/\2\1/;s/\([^A-Z0-9 ]\)/|\1/;s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/;s/|$//' file
```